# How to implement a plugins register like Babel?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to implement a plugins register like Babel? Is typescript support it? If not, why?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoBsCuBzUBJcaeJZAb2QChlrkAHKUMALmQAoBKZAXgD5kA3APbAAJgG4KAXwoVGRRCgw5QAYUEgAzmCiYEYQVAA8AFT6kqNEBADurWujhgYBgLYsMj51BcAaZINowYHUNAH4WY3Z3LFwQAkhYBSkZMABPWkUY0ABlCDAgkGwTZAgAD0gQEQ00LJA1TW1dfSM4EFSePi5kAG0LYx8Leq0dPQNUOCg4FzzoDRMeboBGAF0KZYkKBAcNao8nV0MAaRLyiErd2tz80CLW9u7l7h7ls0oaZAQQxtGoVgCgkIsczvd72ZQgK4FbAaFiHAbvSScUjSaQyLZwHY1cEAQTIFmonwaI2adgc+280U8rj8-2CmiByDgLGGN2QiLIbPxdAY4A4HJRaO2F3BACE8e9CcMmgZSVSKTU5b5-IE6TCOQAjFggTAudXQNlIzmgnlgPnkAWbL50J5WawK8kuVjAmhg2KQm5q3ogmjdJSxbF+chM5CLABMAGY2cs-AB6GPIACipQyekZIBKUCgBmQ6swYGQIEEXPevtqIsDOZYAHI4OqEFWo7H40mU-nWhms1Ac3mC0X3tGpOwKEA)

```
class PluginA {
    constructor(platform: Platform, options: { a: string }) { }
    print() { }
}

class PluginB {
    constructor(platform: Platform, options: { b: number }) { }
    print() { }
}

const p = new Platform({
    pluginSettings: [
        [PluginA, { a: 123 }], // Expect an error but no
        [PluginB, { b: 'abc' }], // Expect an error but no
    ],
})
```

I expect the `[PluginA, { a: 123 }]` has type of `[typeof PluginA, { a: string }]` and `[PluginB, { a: 'abc' }]` has type of `[typeof PluginB, { a: number }]`, but it is not.

Comment: Where's the constructor for `Platform`? since you're creating a `Platform` object.

Comment: @pai.not.pi The link above provides a relatively complete example